# post_parent using multiple id display contents

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I'm having problems posting the contents of the child of my parent page. Currently I'm using to code to post the contents.

```
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) {
            while ( have_posts() ) { the_post();
                $thispage=$post->ID;
            }
        } ?>
    <?php $childpages = query_posts('orderby=date&order=asc&post_type=page&post_parent='.$thispage);
        if($childpages){ 
            echo '<ul class="page-content services">';
                foreach ($childpages as $post):
                setup_postdata($post); ?>
                <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clearfix clinics'); ?> role="article">
                    <?php if (get_the_content()): ?>
                        <div class="page-content">
                                <div class="subpage-header"><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong><?php the_content();?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?> 
         <?php
            endforeach;
            echo '</div></article>';
         } ?>
```

I've manage to reuse this code but this only generates 1 content for the `.$thispage` page. what I want is to use multiple ID's I've tried making using this.

```
 <?php $childpages = query_posts('orderby=date&order=asc&post_type=page&post_parent=1, 2, 3, 4');
```

But it throws different contents not from the ID's 1, 2, 3 and 4.

also used the array but not quite sure on how to write the correct format.

```
<?php $childpages = query_posts('orderby=date&order=asc&post_type=page&post_parent__in=array(1, 2)');
```

This throws the error - array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array, implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Tried this also still throws an error same as above

```
<?php 
$subs = array('1491','1493');
$childpages = query_posts('orderby=date&order=asc&post_type=page&post__in='.$subs);
```

I've check this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37446820/how-to-pass-multiple-ids-to-post-parent) but seems different format for the query tried but doesn't work

tried doing this:

```
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) {
            while ( have_posts() ) { the_post();
                $thispage=$post->ID;
                $pageone = '1491';
            }
        } ?>
    <?php 
    $childpages = query_posts('orderby=title&order=asc&post_type=page&post_parent='.$pageone);
```

not sure if I can add multiple ID's here `$pageone = '1491';` or add multiple variables here `query_posts('orderby=title&order=asc&post_type=page&post_parent='.$pageone);`

Comment: The first step is to rewrite `query_posts` to `WP_Query( $args )` , since the former is not recommended since it modifies the main query. Then you might try `post_parent__in` as an array of post IDs.